# Clearing tkinter canvas content doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

I have a tkinter canvas where a label and a matplotlib plot are shown. I want to update the content of the canvas and therefore delete what was shown before. To do this I found that `canvas.delete('all')` is the way to do this. According to the code below the canvas is filled with content and afterwards deleted. But instead of getting an empty window the content is shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# data for plot
x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [1, 2, 3]

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="grey")
plot_title = tk.Label(canvas, text="plot", font=("Arial 24 bold"), background="grey")

# plot
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
fig.set_facecolor("grey")
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot1.scatter(x1, y1)
chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, canvas)
chart1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
plot_title.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
canvas.delete('all')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `FigureCanvasTkAgg` you have to clear the figure instead of the canvas using `fig.clear()`.

if you want to clear all the data in the canvas then you should destroy it with `canvas.destroy()` then create another canvas in its place, alternatively if you want to delete the label specifically you can just call `plot_title.grid_forget()` or `plot_title.destroy()`

**Edit:** to keep this information out of comments for future readers, as noted by @acw1668 a label is not a canvas item and so it cannot be removed by `.delete("all")`, and only items in tk `item types` in the documentation can be removed by it https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html

Comment: This indeed works for the plot. But I need to get rid of the whole content so the label, too.

Comment: The label is not a canvas item and so it cannot be removed by `.delete("all")`.

Comment: @acw1668 Then I wonder what items are considered as canvas items and can be removed with `canvas.delete('all')`. Can you tell me?

Comment: @Plantz check its documentation for `item types` https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html

Comment: @AhmedAEK Found that widgets are considered as canvas items. Snippet from the documentation: "This can be a lowly button, an entry (think in-place editing of text items), a listbox, a frame itself containing a complex set of widgets... anything!" I'm glad that you are telling me but the documentation is far from being clear which widgets are canvas items and which are not.

Comment: Items created by those `.create_xxxxx()` functions.

Comment: @Plantz the documentation specifies things drawn with `create_window` classify to be deleted, so a label that is `grid` in the canvas doesn't qualify.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Now I found what you mean. It is not said in the text but written "between the lines" of this code `b = ttk.Button(canvas, text='Implode!')` `canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=b)`. Sorry, as a beginner it is very hard to understand such documentations.